# sdl setup visual studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio, installation, sdl

I can not get sdl up and running. I included the include folder, the library folder

and here is the code

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)==-1)
    {

        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

It gives me this error message

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_main referenced in function _main    c:\Users\user1\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Sdl Test 1\Sdl Test 1\SDLmain.lib(SDL_win32_main.obj)  Sdl Test 1
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   c:\users\user1\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Sdl Test 1\Debug\Sdl Test 1.exe    1   1   Sdl Test 1
```

EDIT: I got it working It is because I did not use this

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Comment: put you solution in an answer and accept it so that this question can get solved please.

Comment: thanks I did not know to do that

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I got it working It is because I did not use this

int main(int argc, char* argv[])